# RxJava operator that combines two observables and emits as soon as first observable emits

Tags: android, rx-java

**Problem:**
I have a feature where the user can enter a query string, and I make 2 observables, one to query my local DB and the other to fetch results from an API. These 2 operations have to run in parallel.
I need to show the results from DB as soon as its available, and when API results return, I need to do a check to remove duplicates with the local results.

**My approach:**
[CombineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) seems to be the closest thing to what I need. But the problem is it emits only when both the observables emit the result. I think what I'm looking for is a mix of the CombineLatest and [Concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) operators.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
public void performSearchAsync(String query) {
    Observable<List<LocalSearchResult>> localObservable = Observable.just(performLocalSearch(query))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<Response<List<ApiSearchResult>>> apiObservable = SearchApi.INSTANCE.getSearchResults(query)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    Observable.combineLatest(localObservable, apiObservable, (localSearchResults, listResponse) -> {
        SearchResultWrapper wrapper = new SearchResultWrapper();
        wrapper.localResults = localSearchResults;
        //hold all local result strings in a variable
        List<String> localResultNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (LocalSearchResult localSearchResult : localSearchResults) {
            localResultNames.add(localSearchResult.name);
        }

        if (!listResponse.isSuccessful()) {
            return wrapper;
        }
        wrapper.apiResults = listResponse.body();

        //Do simple de-dupe
        List<ApiSearchResult> deDupedResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ApiSearchResult apiResult : wrapper.apiResults) {
            if (!localResultNames.contains(apiResult.name)) {
                deDupedResults.add(apiResult);
            }
        }
        wrapper.apiResults = deDupedResults;
        return wrapper;
    }).distinctUntilChanged(searchResultWrapper -> searchResultWrapper.localResults)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchResultWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(SearchResultWrapper searchResultWrapper) {
                    if (searchResultWrapper == null) return;
                    if (searchResultWrapper.localResults != null && !searchResultWrapper.localResults.isEmpty()) {
                        //add to view
                        applySearchResult(searchResultWrapper.localResults);
                    }
                    if (searchResultWrapper.apiResults == null || searchResultWrapper.apiResults.isEmpty())
                        return;
                    //add to view
                    apiSearchResultsAdapter.updateResults(searchResultWrapper.apiResults);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }
            });
}

static class SearchResultWrapper {
    List<LocalSearchResult> localResults;
    List<ApiSearchResult> apiResults;
}
```

Here I'm assuming that my local query is always faster than the API, and in the off-chance that it is slower, I want the operator to emit only after the local DB observable has emitted. I know the de-dupe logic can be improved, it is just a sample representation, but I want it to happen within that function where I    have both results.

I'd also like the local results to be emitted and available to the user even if the API observable throws error, although I'm not sure if that would be possible with this structure.

Hope my explanation is clear enough, and someone can suggest a suitable approach to tackle this. I am also considering writing my own operator, although I've heard that is quite tricky.

Comment: Maybe `merge` suits you? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: You say the 2 operations have to run in parallel but you use `Observable.just` for the local results, which means `performLocalSearchQuery()` will run synchronously. You should wrap the `just` with `Observable.defer` to make `performLocalSearchQuery()` run on the `io` scheduler.

Comment: @JanosBreuer Yup, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have wrapped the `just` with `Observable.defer` as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need make it too complex. Just use `merge` or `concat`  and `doOnNext` could be fine.

for example(sorry I use kotlin here):

```
    // actually here is a mistake. Observable.just() receive a item rather than a expression.
    // you should use Observable.fromCallable() instead.
    val localObservable = Observable.fromCallable { performLocalSearch(query) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())


    val apiObservable = SearchApi.INSTANCE.getFoodSearchResults(query)
        .doOnNext {
            //do your check here
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map{
            //map it to the same type with local
        }


    localObservable.mergeWith { apiObservable}
```

or you can use `concatWith` instead of `mergeWith` that can make your api call guaranteed to be called after localObservable Done.

Comment: I take your point about mapping one object to the other, to simpify. I had considered it myself. Also, in this approach, I would need to hold a global reference to the local search results, to compare it the doOnNext block of the apiObservable, right?

Comment: @hari_shankar yes. You need to compare that result. If you don't want to. you can do it with `scan` which will cache a value for you and compute with it.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back. I was able to get it working with your solution. I mapped the API result to local one, and applied a `mergeDelayError` operator so that error in one stream doesn't break the other. Also used `scan` operator to remove duplicates.